# How set any application as default from my application?

Tags: java, android

I'm write launcher switcher. Android show list of installed launchers when I press HOME button. How hide this list or get Home button press event?

Comment: It is up to the user to check the box that says something like "Use my choice as the default" and then select your application. After that the list will no longer appear. As far as I know there is not a way for your application to make that choice for the user.

Comment: My application isn't launcher and missing in the list. I want that my application open one launcher on portrait orientation of screen and other on landscape. This is works, but when user press HOME button, open default launcher.

Comment: So is your application supposed to be a home screen replacement? I don't think I understand what you are trying to accomplish can you elaborate any more?

Comment: My app isn't a home screen replacement. My app is service which monitoring screen orientation of device. When screen orientation change, my app open launcher for this orientation. Anything else?

Comment: I know for certain Some devices don't provide a landscape home screen. And the ones that do provide one generally make it so that the user can set it up so that it will rotate automatically. I think on the devices which your application is actually able to function it will be redundant because the system is already capable of it.

Comment: I have 2 launchers. One launcher with only portrait orientation. This is bookshelf. Оther launcher I want use only for landscape orientation. I want that launchers auto switch. I don't want create own launcher.

Answer (score 1):

What you want is not possible, for obvious security reasons. A malware author could use this feature to replace XYZ app with their own fake XYZ app to attempt to steal private information, without the user's knowledge.

Answer (score 0):

I have solved this issue. I used the method addPreferredActivity of the PowerManager to set default launcher. This method is deprecated and requires a platform key, but I have not found any other way.